# I'm having problem with this equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

So I was solving some determinant and got to this $(x-2)(x^2-4x+5)-(x-1)-(x-1)=0$.
So I know there should be 3 solutions, and I know I can do like $x-2=0$ and $x^2-4x+5=0$ but what do I do with the rest of it? I was trying to include $(x-1)$ but I got this $(x-2)(x^2-4x+5-1)-x=0$ and I don't know what should I do with x then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation is given by
$$
x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 8 =0,
$$
which has no integer roots. In fact, there are two complex solutions and one real solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at your problem as : find the intersection of the curve defined by
$ y = (x-2)(x^2-4x+5)$
and the straight line defined by
$ y = 2 (x-1)$

The first function has only one root at $x=2$ (you can easily show that $(x^2-4x+5) = 0$   does not have any real root). Computing the derivative of the first function shows it does not cancel with real solution. The second derivative of the first function cancels at $x=2$ which is an inflection point; remember that at this point the value of the function is equal to $0$.

So, to summarize, the first function grows from minus infinity to plus infinity and it has to intersect the second function which has a positive slope and which has a positive value for $x=2$ but which grows slower that the first function. So, you have only one real root which is greater than 2; by inspection, you could easily show that the solution is somewhere between $x=3$ and $x=4$. In practice, the solution corresponds to $x=3.52138$).